# Kenburner Slider not working in IE

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

Currently I am working on a [website](http://tourdigger.com/tourdigger) and I used Kenburner Slider in the home page.

The Slider is working fine on Firefox and Chrome but it's not working in IE7 and lower versions. Can any one suggest what steps should I take?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in IE8- for me. I noticed it's canvas based, IE8- don't have support for canvas at all.

Comment: Are you talking about this one? http://www.themepunch.com/codecanyon/kenburner/

Comment: It might not be the Kenburner causing your trouble.  You have 30 different referenced scripts (20 are scripts you are hosting on your server) which include an old version of jQuery (1.5) and a newer version of jQuery UI 1.8.13.  Maybe it's the combination of several resources all on the same page

Answer (score 1):

According to their FAQ, you should this to the top of your page before any html code `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Check the link [slider faq](http://wowslider.com/faq.html)

**EDIT, additional info:**

If I visit the link [themepunch kenburner](http://www.themepunch.com/codecanyon/kenburner/) while using the developer tools F12 and simulate my browser mode to IE7 or IE8 the slider works. Have you viewed the source and checked out the meta tags, such as "" ? I also see the site is using jquery 1.7, its possible if you are using a later version it might not be compatible.

Comment: But I am not use wowslider. It's kenburner slider. By the way I follow your instruction but nothing change.

Comment: Apologies, a google search turned up a reference to that. Can you provide a link to the source site please?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should post your code. According to their site, [link](http://codecanyon.net/item/kenburner-slider-jquery-plugin/1249801), it does work in IE7 (and by visiting the example site in IE7, I can confirm that).

Maybe you should check the example site to match your code with how it is supposed to be. At last your code should be something like:

```
jQuery('#banner-example-1').kenburn(
{
    width:800,
    height:320,
    thumbWidth:120,
    thumbHeight:70,
    thumbAmount:6,
    thumbSpaces:0,
    thumbPadding:9,
    thumbStyle:"both",
    bulletXOffset:0,
    bulletYOffset:-80,
    repairChromeBug:"on",
    shadow:'true',
    timerShow:"on",
    touchenabled:'on',
    pauseOnRollOverThumbs:'off',
    pauseOnRollOverMain:'on',
    preloadedSlides:10,
    timer:10
});
```